# How can I print " *cp " using (Return address )function??( please refer my code)

Tags: c++

1. Is there any Algorithms error when I use (Return address)function(`int*returnsum(int*par,int*pbr)`)??
2. Is there any logical error when the value("c") moves from returnsum to printresult??
   ( there is no error when I execute the program!! )

---

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int* returnsum(int* par, int* pbr);
void printresult(int* cp);

int main()
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int* pa = &a;
    int* pb = &b;
    int* c;
    cout << "Enter two numbers:";
    cin >> a >> b;
    c=returnsum(pa, pb);
    printresult(c);
    return 0;
}

int* returnsum(int*par,int*pbr)
{
    int sum=0;
    sum = *par + *pbr;
    
    return &sum;
}
void printresult(int *cp)
{
    cout << *cp;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any Algorithms error when I use (Return address)function(int*returnsum(int*par,int*pbr))??

Yes, you are returning the address of a local variable that has gone out of scope. This is a dangling pointer and it is Undefined Behaviour to dereference it.

> Is there any logical error when the value("c") moves from returnsum to printresult??

There would not be if the pointer `c` was valid, but it is not because of the above. Do yourself a favour here and forget about pointers, just return by value. You do not gain anything by returning a pointer in this case.

> ( there is no error when I execute the program!! )

In cases of undefined behaviour the program may appear to work correctly. But this does not mean that it is correct.